# Finding out whether a TCP server has sent a data

Tags: c#, tcp

1. I have a TCP server which writes data back to the client only for certain messages which the clients sends to the server.
2. It is basically is a command based server for which the server responds with a string only for certain commands otherwise nothing is sent back to the client.
3. The code given below is an approach which assumes that if any data is sent by the server it shows it as "MESSAGE FROM SERVER" appended with the data which was sent.

   ```
       class TcpEchoClient
       {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
       Console.WriteLine("Starting echo client...");


               string ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
               TcpClient client = null;
               NetworkStream netstream = null;

               try
               {

                   client = new TcpClient(ipaddress,1000);
                   netstream = client.GetStream();

               }
               catch
               {
                   Console.ReadKey();
                   Environment.Exit(0);
               }


               while(true)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Message :  ");
                   string t = Console.ReadLine();
                   string readdata = null;
                   Console.WriteLine("\n");


                   if (write(t,netstream))
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");

                       if (client.Available!=0)
                       {
                           readdata = read(netstream);
                           Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE FROM SERVER : "+readdata);
                       }


                   }
                   else
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine("Unable to send message.");
                   }
               }


           }

           static bool write(string dat, NetworkStream stream) 
           {

               try
               {

                   StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };


                   try{writer.WriteLine(dat);}
                   catch (IOException){return false;}

                   if (SHAHash(dat, "DATA") != SHAHash(read(stream), "DATA"))
                       return false;
               }catch (InvalidOperationException){return false;}


               return true;        
           }

           static string read(NetworkStream stream)
           {

               StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

               string readdata = null;

               try
               {
                   readdata = reader.ReadLine();
                   reader.BaseStream.Flush();
               }
               catch(IOException)
               {
                   return null;
               }

               return readdata;
           }
   }
   ```

The function SHAHash is not shown in this post. Its format is SHAHash(message,salt).

The problem faced is that messages sent by the server is not always read by the client. Sometimes the data sent by the server shows up a the client console, and sometimes it does not.

What correction should I make to the above code so that I can read data from the server only when it sends it. That is I require the following code to be executed only when the server sends some data to the client otherwise it should not be executed.

```
readdata = read(netstream);
Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE FROM SERVER : "+readdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Be prudent when using flush or autoflush. Sometimes it executes before send/receive operations... but this usually happens when working with threads.

My first tip that the stream readers/writers are not destructed properly. Try packing them into a using statement.

Answer (score 0):

TCP isnt synchronous so you can't write data and expect the response to be available immediately. When you do the following check

```
if (client.Available!=0)
```

there is no guarantee that the server has sent any response yet. You need to keep checking until there is data available or read the data asynchronously

I would use NetworkStream.BeginRead and callbacks to get the server response

```
class StreamData
{

    public NetworkStream netstream;

    public byte[] myReadBuffer;
}


class TcpEchoClient
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting echo client...");

        string ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
        TcpClient client = null;
        NetworkStream netstream = null;

        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(ipaddress, 13000);
            netstream = client.GetStream();
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        var streamData = new StreamData
        {
            netstream = netstream,
            myReadBuffer = new byte[1024],
        };

        netstream.BeginRead(streamData.myReadBuffer, 0, streamData.myReadBuffer.Length,
                                                   new AsyncCallback(myReadCallBack),
                                                   streamData);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message :  ");
            string t = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            if (write(t, netstream))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to send message.");
            }
        }
    }

    static void myReadCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var streamData = (StreamData)ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesRead = streamData.netstream.EndRead(ar);
        var readdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(streamData.myReadBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
        //Be aware that this might not be the complete message depending on the size of the message and the buffer size
        Console.WriteLine("You received the following message : " + readdata);

        //Start waiting for more data
        streamData.netstream.BeginRead(streamData.myReadBuffer, 0, streamData.myReadBuffer.Length,
                                                   new AsyncCallback(myReadCallBack),
                                                   streamData);
    }

    static bool write(string dat, NetworkStream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };

            try { writer.WriteLine(dat); }
            catch (IOException) { return false; }

            //if (SHAHash(dat, "DATA") != SHAHash(read(stream), "DATA"))
            //    return false;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException) { return false; }

        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Is there any scope for using threads in this scenario (not asynchronous programming) ?

Comment: I would use NetworkStream.BeginRead, I have included a basic example

Comment: Are there no efficient method to do it synchronously (possibly in combination with threads).

Comment: You can wait till you read something from the socket or timeout if the server sends nothing. More efficient would be to get the server to always send a response.